# Dual 27" Thunderbolt

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt, daisy-chaining

How can I set up a dual Thunderbolt on a 2012 Mac mini server? I daisy chained them but the second stays black.

Do I need a Thunderbolt to HDMI adaptor, from which vendor, how can I not lose resolution?

Or does this setting work only with the non-server Mac mini with the AMD Radeon HD 6630M graphics card?

http://www.apple.com/macmini/features.html

Answer (score 4):

You need the 2.5 Ghz Mac Mini, which indeed also comes with an AMD Radeon HD 6630M instead of the integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 on the 2.3Ghz model.

For a list of models that support up to two Thunderbolt displays connected, check this support article over on the Apple website:

[Thunderbolt ports and displays: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#dispnum)

- 14 - How many Apple Thunderbolt Displays can I use with my Mac in OS X?